# Unsure of type to use in an event subscription method

Tags: c#, action

I was trying to create a general function, that should describe some threads to the windows event log to different internal methods. So i wrote:

```
void SubScribeToEventLogEvent(string EventLog,int EventID,string Source, Action named ="myMethod")
{
    string query = "*[System/Level=8] and [System/EventID=" +EventID.ToString()+"]";

    EventLogQuery subscriptionQuery = new EventLogQuery(EventLog, PathType.LogName, "*[System/Level=8]");
    EventLogWatcher watcher = new EventLogWatcher(subscriptionQuery);
    watcher.EventRecordWritten += new EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(named);
    watcher.Enabled = true;
}
```

Then I have a few functions triggered for specific events

```
private void myMethod(object obj,EventRecordWrittenEventArgs arg)
{
    //do something
    if (arg.EventRecord != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(arg.EventRecord.Id.ToString() + arg.EventRecord.FormatDescription());
        Console.WriteLine("Received event {0} from the subscription.", arg.EventRecord.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", arg.EventRecord.FormatDescription());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The event instance was null.");
    }
}
```

So that in my main I could simply write

`SubScribeToEventLogEvent(EventlogName,200,myMethod);`

However it doesn't seam to work, I am coding in .net 4.0 and I believed that Action is a reserved method word for doing such things. But I get an error (red line already under named in the first line of the code):

`SubScribeToEventLogEvent(string EventLog,int EventID,string Source, Action named ="myMethod")`

apparently it cann't be assigned a string value (but what else?), and if I remove the string value its still not recognized in the Eventhandler function.

Comment: do you have user defined type called `Action`? else it's confused if you are talking about Action delegate

Comment: `Action` is indeed not a String: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, `Action named ="myMethod"` is absolutely incorrect. Not sure why you're even doing that.  "named" should be of type `EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>` and it (possibly) should work. You can't sub to an event with just the name of the method. You'd have to have an instance and use reflection to get a delegate to that instance's method.

Comment: @will, hm my intentions are to sub with a name of a method, are there maybe other ways to do that ?.

Comment: **"named" should be of type `EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>`** You can simply pass the method in and += `named` directly to the event.

Comment: `void SubScribeToEventLogEvent(string EventLog, int EventID, string Source, EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs> named )` does work in the void itself but then i cannot do ' SubScribeToEventLogEvent(EventlogName,200,myMethod);`

Comment: Not enough arguments?